# Excluding .js files in git repository of coffeescript project

Tags: javascript, git, coffeescript

Do development teams that deal with coffee-script projects exclude compiled .js files from their git repos and simply track .coffee files while expecting developers to compile .coffee files to js when testing?

Comment: Looks promising............

Comment: The outlook is grim.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd exclude them if I were you. They are a build artifact.

Have a full build task that generates the js

When you make simple changes that aren't related to coffeescript your devs can run the incremental task that doesn't include the building of the js as its using an already existing build artifact.